# Image rescaling/sizing with CSS bootstrap "Jumbotron"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had what seemed like a pretty easy problem to solve, my jumbotron image is not scaled correctly; leaving a rather large image (5560 × 1592) a little bit blurry:

[image]

My index.html is the following:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">
        <astrobox>astrobox</astrobox>
        <io>.io</io>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
    </div>
    <div class="jumbotron_paragraphs">
        <p><p1>$Supporting /[] Professional_Astronomers<p1></p>
        <p><p2>Serving the research of those studying in the field of astronomy and astrophysics.</p2></p>
        <div class="learn_more">
        <p><a href="#">Learn More</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS is:

```
.jumbotron {
  background-image:url('https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8679/16635810101_037dda36eb_s.jpg');
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  top:10px;
}

.jumbotron astrobox {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 100px;  
  font-family: 'Basic', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
}

.jumbotron io {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;  
  font-family: 'Lobster', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
}

.jumbotron .container p {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: verdana;
}

.jumbotron_paragraphs p1 {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.jumbotron_paragraphs p2 {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}
```

Any hints or tips on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what result you are expecting? The image referenced in your CSS is only 75x75px not 5560x1592px... fitting that into a large div will surely result in pixelmania. Maybe I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Yes, I've just seen that. flikr used to be useful! What would be the best place to store an image online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So flikr seems to be really poor at displaying the image and hosting photos...why have they made their service worse? Dropbox is 100% better for the jumbotron images.

```
.jumbotron {
    background-image:url('https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/xxx.jpg?_subject_uid=xxx');
    height: 520px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover
}

.jumbotron .title {
    text-align: center;
}

.jumbotron .container {
    position: relative;
    top:10px;
}

.jumbotron astrobox {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: 'Basic', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
}

.jumbotron io {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-family: 'Lobster', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
}

.jumbotron .container p {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
}

.jumbotron_paragraphs p1 {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.jumbotron_paragraphs p2 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.jumbotron_paragraphs .jumbotron_image {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```